# Is the interference quantum mechanical superposition the same as entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, interference, wave-particle-duality, superposition

Are the interference of two wave functions an equivalent way of saying that they are entangled?

Comment: Why would you think so? *Entanglement* is a property of quantum system, but *interference* of waves also happens classically. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I meant the interference of the wave functions of quantum particles in a superposition, not some classical wavess such as a water waves just interfering of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Quantum Entanglement and Quantum Superposition be considered the same phenomenon?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148131/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Quantum Mechanics interferences is when the wave function of one (or more) particle can take several paths and then later cross. The complex amplitude adds up and you have an interference. Negative interference if the probability gets smaller at one point or positive if the probability gets higher. The definition is mostly qualitative here.

Entanglement is between two or more particle (or degrees of freedom, to be more general). It can be measured quantitatively. It's when the state of one particle depends on the state of the second. Like |up>|up> + |down>|down>  fully entangled.
But |up>|up> + |down>|down> + |down> |up> + |up>|down>  are not entangled because you can factorize it

The two concepts are different.

Answer (score 0):

They are different things.

**Interference** Is an intrinsically quantum phenomenon that arises form the fact that transition probabilities between different pure states can be non-zero, as opposed to classical mechanics, where such transition probability is always zero.

**Entanglement** Is a property of a state of a composite system, expressed as the tensor product of two or more parts. The state is said to be entangled with respect to a certain tensor product representation if it cannot be written as the tensor product of vector states from each of the tensor factors.

Although it is possible to talk about *single particle entanglement*, one usually consider states that involve different (possibly independent) parts, which are combined together by a direct (i.e. tensor) product. On the other hand interference can take place within the same single system, and of course in a combined system as well.

Comment: It depends on the context but interference is a wave phenomenon which is seen in classical physics as well.

Comment: I'd say this is clearly not the context of classical physics, so classical interference of waves can be ruled out.

Comment: @Phoenix87 But, would interference between the waves of two quantum objects in a superposition be an equivalent way of saying that they are entangled or is it the effect of their entanglement.

Comment: For entangled states you can choose a vector state which factorises in the tensor product, so with this choice there is no superposition. Of course you can take an arbitrary base for the tensor product Hilbert space and decompose the entangled state in a superposition of other states, so as you can see from this there is no direct link between entanglement and superposition.